# $X_n=n^21_{(0,1/n)}$. What is $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

$X_n=n^21_{(0,1/n)}$. What is $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n$? What about its $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n$?

My attempt:
For each $n$ on $\{0, [1/n,1]\}$, we have $X_n=0$.Also Lebesgue measure of the set $(0,1/n)$ is $1/n$,which goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. Does it mean that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n=0$. If I am right shouldn't I add  a.s.?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with? If you select a number $c \in (0, 1)$, then what can you say about $$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(c)$$

Comment: Sorry but "For each $n$ on $\{0, [1/n,1]\}$ $X_n=0$" simply does not parse. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that for each n, $X_n$ is zero on $[1/n,1]$ and on the point $0$. (Assuming $\Omega=[0,1]$).

Comment: We're using the convention $\infty \times 0 = 0$